# Sessions in word press

Tags: functions, buddypress, session, wp-load.php

Is it possible to set session in wordpress. If yes can you please tell how to do it? My sample code is.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['impression'])) {
    $_SESSION['impression'] = 100;  
}else {
    if($_SESSION['impression']<=0)
        $_SESSION['impression'] = 100;
}

echo $_SESSION['impression']    = $_SESSION['impression'] -1;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, Session must start before header is sent. So you should try -

```
<?php
if( !session_id() ){
    if( headers_sent() ){
        die('headers already sent, cant start session');
    }
    else{
        session_start();
    }
}

// check existence, or not below 1
if( !isset($_SESSION['impression']) || $_SESSION['impression'] < 1 ){
    $_SESSION['impression'] = 100;  
}

// decrease the value by one
$_SESSION['impression']--;

// test
echo $_SESSION['impression'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `$_SESSION` in wordpress...
Because `$_SESSION` is disabled by wordpress...

You can check in "wp-includes/load.php"

```
/**
 * Turn register globals off.
 *
 * @access private
 * @since 2.1.0
 * @return null Will return null if register_globals PHP directive was disabled
 */
function wp_unregister_GLOBALS() {
    if ( !ini_get( 'register_globals' ) )
        return;

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['GLOBALS'] ) )
        die( 'GLOBALS overwrite attempt detected' );

    // Variables that shouldn't be unset
    $no_unset = array( 'GLOBALS', '_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE', '_REQUEST', '_SERVER', '_ENV', '_FILES', 'table_prefix' );

    $input = array_merge( $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SERVER, $_ENV, $_FILES, isset( $_SESSION ) && is_array( $_SESSION ) ? $_SESSION : array() );
    foreach ( $input as $k => $v )
        if ( !in_array( $k, $no_unset ) && isset( $GLOBALS[$k] ) ) {
            unset( $GLOBALS[$k] );
        }
}
```

So if you want to use `$_SESSION`, you might need to use plugins. There are several plugins that allow wordpress to use `$_SESSION`.